# Using "expect" in the future tense

Tags: verbs, future-tense

Today I encountered with these sentences:

> It will be expected to be raining tomorrow.
>
> Society may change, but gender roles won’t be expected to change with it.

Is this usage of "expect" with future tense and passive form correct? Really it seems unnatural and strange to me.

Comment: Please do not vote to close this question.  The current vote indicates a fundamental misunderstanding of what the question is asking.  S.H.W. is not asking to fix the sentences, but rather whether this use of "expect" in the future tense is reasonable.  Perhaps it could use more detail, but calling it "proofreading" is entirely specious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not unusual, but I too am of the opinion that it's often awkward and redundant, as in both your examples.  It's fine to use the passive tense with "expect", but there's no need to push it into the future:

> It **is expected** to rain tomorrow.
>
> Society may change, but gender roles **aren't expected** to change with it.

The only time this ever makes sense is if it is reasonable to push the expectation itself into the future.  This must be supported by context:

> Agriculture will always be the foundation of a healthy society.  Centuries from now, meals **will be expected** to arrive on time to feed hungry future generations, no matter what their original source.

I still prefer the active voice:

> Centuries from now, hungry future generations **will expect** their meals to arrive on time, no matter what their original source.

but I've forced it into the passive to make it similar to your examples.

Comment: Thanks, I think the reason for using "expect" in the future tense(in the mentioned paragraph) is showing the constant need for agriculture. Is that right?

Comment: @S.H.W   The expectation is itself **in the future**, that's why it makes sense to use the future tense.  It's just as easy to say the same thing without using "expect" at all, for example, *"in the future, as today, meals **must** be delivered on time"*